# One form, multiple group values for PHP

Tags: php, html

What I would like to do is to use a single form to host different groups of input like shown in the example. I use the pseudo-property "group", so when the php receives the input, it can differentiate between par1 received from group1 or from group2. While the example presents just 2 groups for clarity, the application I am building requires half a hundred such groups on different pages, so I would like to avoid using multiple forms, if possible:

```
<form action='main.php'  method='post'>
<input type='submit' value='Group1' name='Action' group='Group1'>
<input type='hidden' value='543' name='par1' group='Group1'>
<input type='hidden' value='123' name='par2' group='Group1'>
<input type='hidden' value='269' name='par3' group='Group1'>
<input type='submit' value='Group1' name='Action' group='Group2'>
<input type='hidden' value='543' name='par1' group='Group2'>
<input type='hidden' value='123' name='par2' group='Group2'>
<input type='hidden' value='269' name='par3' group='Group2'>
</form>
```

Comment: Mostly to avoid 100+ additional lines. Practically for optimization reasons.

Comment: Instead of using `group='Group1'`, you could make your input names arrays, with the key the group -> `name='par1[Group1]'` or `name='Group1[par1]'`. Then on form submit, in php you can group all values by the group.

Comment: You can use `name='par1[]'` for all inputs.  In `php`, you get the data in the array: `$_POST['par1']`. Items are distinguishable by their index in the array.

Comment: This sounds like the right path to go, but I do not know how to read the key with PHP. I will know what key I need through the value of the relative submit, but how could I turn that value to a variable name? Making a function to connect values with keys would again lead to a massive block of repeated code.

Comment: Oh, I think I figured it out. Two dimensions. `name='par[Group1][1]'`. So I can use the value of the submit for the first dimension! Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP only needs you to assign the same names to the related fields, and a different index for each field in the same group, example (I used "fieldset" and "legend" to make it prettier), notice the inputs have the name "group1[x]" and "group2[x]" :

```
<form action='my_script.php'  method='post'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 1</legend>  
    <br/>
    <input type='hidden' value='111' name='group1[0]'>
    <br/>
    <input type='hidden' value='222' name='group1[1]'>
    <br/>
    <input type='hidden' value='333' name='group1[2]'>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 2</legend>  
    <br/>
    <input type='hidden' value='444' name='group2[0]'>
    <br/>
    <input type='hidden' value='555' name='group2[1]'>
    <br/>
    <input type='hidden' value='666' name='group2[2]'>
  </fieldset>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit form" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Now, on the PHP side, you get the data like this:

```
<?php 
if ( isset( $_POST[ "submit" ] ) )
   { $group1 = $_POST[ "group1" ];
     $group2 = $_POST[ "group2" ];
     print_r( $group1 );
     echo "<br/><br/>";
     print_r( $group2 );
   }
?>
```

If you create two text files with PHP extension and copy-paste previous code, you will see on screen something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 111 [1] => 222 [2] => 333 )

Array ( [0] => 444 [1] => 555 [2] => 666 )
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jose Manuel Abarca Rodríguez Essentially this is the solution to the problem, with one difference that I didn't probably make clear enough on the initial post: I only need to keep one group on the PHP side, so instead of using `$_POST[ "group1" ];` I need to use `$_POST[ "$_POST[ "submit" ]" ];` so I only get the group that accompanied the relative submit. For future reference I post a complete example of what I mean:

```
<form action='main.php'  method='post'>
<input type='submit' value='Group1' name='Action' group='Group1'>
<input type='hidden' value='123' name=Group1['par1']>
<input type='hidden' value='456' name=Group1['par2']>
<input type='hidden' value='789' name=Group1['par3']>
<input type='submit' value='Group2' name='Action' group='Group2'>
<input type='hidden' value='147' name=Group2['par1']>
<input type='hidden' value='258' name=Group2['par2']>
<input type='hidden' value='369' name=Group2['par3']>
</form>
```

Then on the PHP side:

```
<?php 
if ( isset( $_POST[ "submit" ] ) )
   {
        $par1 = $_POST[ "$_POST[ "submit" ]" ]['par1'];
        $par2 = $_POST[ "$_POST[ "submit" ]" ]['par2'];
        $par3 = $_POST[ "$_POST[ "submit" ]" ]['par3'];
   }
?>
```

I guess though that optimization-wise it's worse than just posting a series of forms since this way the PHP receives the entire block of variables from html, and then keeps only what is required, instead of just receiving the part needed. Thanks you for your contribution!